# Layout is going below the status bar and here is the code i used for layout

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I am facing an issue in my application,  I have to set the image taken from camera as background in the canvas. Am calling default camera to take the pic. After taking the pic, a preview is shown of the image taken and will ask us to save or not, If save and home are pressed at the same time, we will go to the home screen. After this I am launching my application from the applications. When opened, the layout where canvas & buttons are placed is going above the status bar.

**Edited:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:src="@drawable/dbg_bg" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/dd_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="310dip"
            android:layout_height="35dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >



            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/tools"
                android:layout_width="25dip"
                android:layout_height="21dip"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:tag="3"
                 />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/border"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:layout_below="@id/header"
            android:background="@drawable/border" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgbtn"
                android:layout_width="21dip"
                android:layout_height="21dip"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:tag="1"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/pt_imgbtn"
                android:layout_width="24dip"
                android:layout_height="19dip"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:tag="4"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/footer"
            android:layout_below="@id/border" >

            <com.xyz.ddd.canvas.SurfaceCanvas
                android:id="@+id/surfacecanvas"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/footerborder"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:layout_above="@id/footer"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please add some code you tried to write.

Comment: please also post screen shots if possible ...

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar Sorry I could not it's occuring oftenly

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar I added the screen shot

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have both src and background in your `RelativeLayout`?

Remove the one which you don't need.

```
android:background="@color/background"
android:src="@drawable/dbg_bg"
```

Hope this helps.